# How to do Left Void?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I am trying to understand https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Void.html and having the following example:

```
let x :: Either Void Int; x = Left Void
```

The code does not get compiled. How to make it run?

Comment: It's an error because you are trying to pass a type constructor where a value or a data constructor is expected. Void doesn't have a data constructor, and that's the point. You can't create a value of type Void.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point of the `Void` type is that it has no inhabitants (other than "bottom" values like exceptions and infinite loops). You *could* write

```
x, y, z :: Either Void Int
x = undefined
y = Left $ error "Whoops"
z = Left $ let q = q in q
```

but all of these violate the essential concept of `Void`.

The only "legitimate" values of type `Either Void Int` are of the form `Right i`, where `i :: Int`.

Indeed, you can write the following:

```
unEither :: Either Void a -> a
unEither (Left v) = absurd v
unEither (Right a) = a
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `unEither` function is really helpful to someone who doesn't understand what Void is about.

Answer (score 6):

Since it is impossible to ever create a value of type Void, every value of type `Either Void Int` must have a Right constructor (or else a bottom in its Left constructor, which is not very useful). e.g., `Right 1` would be a valid value of this type.